# Tags and @model inside if-block

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my `Footer.cshtml` I've got an switch for authentificated users and check if the model has been supplied.

```cs
@model AngemeldeterBenutzerModel

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Model != null)
{
    <span class="span2">Eingelogt als @model.AnzeigeName</span>
    <span class="offset1 span9">Zuletzt eingelogt mit "@model.LastLoginIp" um "@model.LastLoginDate"</span>
}
```

This view gets rendered in the `_Layout.cshtml` as follows:

```
<div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Footer", "Navigation"); }
</div>
```

However I get this parser error:

> The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

But I closed the `if`-block at the end. I've also tried to surround the content with a `<text>` tag or precede both spans with `@:`.

At which point do I violate the syntax?

Comment: I presume that the properties of the model aren't actually `.Foo` and `.Bar`, can you show the real code?

Comment: Contains now the real code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This violates the syntax:

```
 @model.AnzeigeName
```

All your model.property settings should be uppercase i.e.

```
 @Model.AnzeigeName
```

You could also use `@:` to output, please try the following:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Model != null)
{
    @:<span class="span2">Eingelogt als @Model.AnzeigeName</span>
    @:<span class="offset1 span9">Zuletzt eingelogt mit "@Model.LastLoginIp" um "@Model.LastLoginDate"</span>
}
```